# Missing transitive Maven dependency of local jar

Tags: java, maven

Apologize for using acronyms in advance.

I'm working a Maven project `Foo`, which is depending on a local jar `Bar`. `Bar` is built with Maven as well and since it's a local jar, I created a local repo in `Foo`'s folder structure, and put the jar there.

`Bar.jar` is put at `base_dir_of_Foo\repo\group_ID\artifact_ID\1.0-SNAPSHOT\Bar.jar`.

The problem I'm having is that when I'm running `Foo`, it's throwing a `NoClassDefFoundError`, because it can't find a class in one of `Bar`'s dependencies. So, `Foo` is missing a transitive dependency through `Bar`.

One thing to notice is that when I'm running `mvn clean package` for `Foo`, I saw a warning says "Missing POM for Bar". `Foo` is calling `B` using reflection, and `Foo` is able to find classes defined in `Bar`, but looks like `A` can't figure out `Bar`'s dependencies. Any idea why this is happening?

Local repos is defined in `Foo`'s `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-repo</id>
        <name>Local</name>
       <url>file://${basedir}/repo</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Finally `Foo` is depending on `Bar` with default compile scope:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>group_ID</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact_ID</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update:**
I found of why pom of Bar is not found, it was because we I put Bar.jar at local repo, maven will only copy over the jar file into local repository cache, it will not extract pom.xml from the jar, is this expected?

Inside C:\Users\hancwang.m2\repository\group-id\Bar\1.0-SNAPSHOT, I'm seeing Bar-1.0-snapshot.jar being copied over, but there's no Bar-1.0-snapshot.pom.

Comment: do you build Bar source code with Maven locally?

Comment: Yes, I do, and then I copy Bar.jar to local repo under Foo.

Comment: please try my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `<repository>` definition is probably pointing to an incomplete repository, e.g. a repo missing a `.pom` file.

Assuming you build Bar source code locally, if you run `mvn install` in Bar you will install its artifact in the local repository. This way, Foo will find Bar normally. You don't need to define a `<repository>` in this case.

So, try to:

- Run `mvn install` or `mvn clean install` in Bar
- Remove the `<repository>` definition that points to a `file://` jar

Comment: Problem is that another person can git pull Foo but don't have access to Bar, which will fail build of Foo.

Comment: @HanchiWang can't the other person build Bar source code?

Comment: They can't really, because 1) Foo is open source but Bar is not and 2) I want customers of Foo to be able to run the jar file and mvn package out of box.

Comment: @HanchiWang i'll think of something. Meanwhile put this last comment of yours in the question, for it's a relevant requirement